# how to pass the multiple variable from one php file to another using $_Post method when click on button?

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I have a file which is having multi select drop down, single select drop down, radio buttons, numeric slider in a page.

By default some value will be fetched from database.

When I click on save button, it should pass the default values selected already to another page.

If I make any changes in the drop down values and click on completed, new value which I selected currently should pass to another file.

How can I make it possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- The below url are required for dropdown -->
    <link href="http://localhost/Performance/fselect.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://localhost/Performance/js/fSelect.js"></script>

    <!-- The below url are required for numeric slidebar -->
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.9/angular-material.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.9/docs.css'>

    <style>
    #container{
        height:1000px;
        max-height:400px;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }
    #well{
        background-color: white;
    }
    #testconfig{
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    </style>

    <script>
    (function($) {
        $(function() {  
            $('#filename').fSelect();
            $('#inst_type').fSelect();
            $('#browsers').fSelect();
            $('#region').fSelect();
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: white">
<div>
<form method="post" action="insertdata.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div>
                    <a href=""><h3>Project Name</h3></a>
                </div>
                <div><span><h4>Test Name</h4></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="buttons"><br/>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><b>Duplicate</b></button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><b>Delete test</b></button>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"><b>Save test</b></button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><b>Run test</b></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><hr/>

    <div class="well" id="well">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="btn-group col-md-4">
            <div class="TestHistory">
                <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-4"><b>Test History</b></button>
            </div>
            <div class="TestCofiguration">
                <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-4" id="testconfig"><b>Test Configuration</b></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>

        <div name="toggle" id="hideandshow">
            <div class="row" id="runtest">
                <center><h3>Edit test if you need</h3></center>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row" id="container">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="col-xs-6"><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                                            <span><b>Filename</b></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <select  name="filename[]" id="filename" multiple="multiple">
                                            <optgroup label="Filename">
                                                <?php
                                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_fsql)) {
                                                        $i=0;
                                                        for ($x = 0; $x < count($JmxFiles); $x++) {
                                                            if(strcmp($row['script'],$JmxFiles[$x])==0){
                                                                echo "<option id='file' value='".$row['script']."' selected='selected'>".$row['script']."</option>";
                                                                $i=1;
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        if ($i!=1){
                                                            echo "<option id='file' value='".$row['script']."'>".$row['script']."</option>";
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                            </optgroup>
                                        </select>
                                    </div><br/>

                                    <div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                                            <span><b>Instance Machine Size</b></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <select style="margin-left:1cm" name="inst_type" id="inst_type">
                                            <?php
                                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_inst_sql)) {
                                                if($inst_type==$row['instance_type']){
                                                    echo "<option value='".$inst_type."' selected>".$inst_type."</option>";
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                    echo "<option value='".$row['instance_type']."'>".$row['instance_type']."</option>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div><br/>

                                    <div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                                            <span><b>Browser</b></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <select  name="browsers" id="browsers">
                                            <?php
                                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_bsql)) {
                                                if($browser==$row['browser']){
                                                    echo "<option value='".$browser."' selected>".$browser."</option>";
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                    echo "<option value='".$row['browser']."'>".$row['browser']."</option>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div><br/>

                                    <div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                                            <span><b>Region</b></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <select name="region[]" id="region" multiple="multiple">
                                            <optgroup label="Region">
                                                <?php
                                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_region_name)) {
                                                        $i=0;
                                                        for ($x = 0; $x < count($Region_name); $x++) {
                                                            if(strcmp($row['region_name'],$Region_name[$x])==0){
                                                                echo "<option value='".$row['region_name']."' selected='selected'>".$row['region_name']."</option>";
                                                                $i=1;
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        if ($i!=1){
                                                            echo "<option value='".$row['region_name']."'>".$row['region_name']."</option>";
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                            </optgroup>
                                        </select>
                                    </div><br/>

                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="sliderdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp" style= background-color: white">
                                      <md-content style="margin: 16px; padding:10px; background-color: white">

                                        <md-slider-container>
                                          <span class="md-body-1 col-xs-4"><b>Concurrency</b></span>
                                          <?php echo'<md-slider ng-model="disabled" min="1" max="100" aria-label="Disabled" md-discrete="" id="blue-slider" class="md-primary" style="margin-left: 60px;">';?>
                                          </md-slider>
                                          </md-slider>
                                          <md-input-container>
                                            <?php echo'<input type="number" id="Concurrency" name="Concurrency" ng-model="disabled" min="1" max="100" ng-init="disabled='.$users.'" aria-label="blue" aria-controls="blue-slider">';?>
                                          </md-input-container>
                                        </md-slider-container>

                                        <md-slider-container>
                                          <span class="md-body-1 col-xs-4"><b>Iteration</b></span>
                                          <?php echo'<md-slider ng-model="disabled1" min="1" max="50" aria-label="Disabled1" md-discrete="" id="blue-slider" class="md-primary"  style="margin-left: 60px;">';?>
                                          </md-slider>
                                          </md-slider>
                                          <md-input-container>
                                            <?php echo'<input type="number" id="Iteration" name="Iteration" ng-model="disabled1" min="1" max="50" ng-init="disabled1='.$iteration.'" aria-label="blue" aria-controls="blue-slider">';?>
                                          </md-input-container>
                                        </md-slider-container>

                                        <md-slider-container>
                                          <span class="md-body-1 col-xs-4"><b>Rampup(sec)</b></span>
                                          <?php echo'<md-slider ng-model="disabled2" min="0" max="100" aria-label="Disabled2" md-discrete="" id="blue-slider" class="md-primary"  style="margin-left: 60px;">';?>
                                          </md-slider>
                                          </md-slider>
                                          <md-input-container>
                                            <?php echo'<input type="number" id="ramp-up" name="ramp-up" ng-model="disabled2" min="0" max="100" ng-init="disabled2='.$rampup.'" aria-label="blue" aria-controls="blue-slider">';?>
                                          </md-input-container>
                                        </md-slider-container>

                                        <md-slider-container>
                                          <span class="md-body-1 col-xs-4"><b>Timeout(sec)</b></span>
                                          <?php echo'<md-slider ng-model="disabled3" min="1" max="300" aria-label="Disabled3" md-discrete="" id="blue-slider" class="md-primary"  style="margin-left: 60px;">';?>
                                          </md-slider>
                                          </md-slider>
                                          <md-input-container>
                                            <?php echo '<input type="number" id="timeout" name="timeout" ng-model="disabled3" min="1" max="300" ng-init="disabled3='.$time_out.'" aria-label="blue" aria-controls="blue-slider">';?>
                                          </md-input-container>
                                        </md-slider-container>

                                        <md-slider-container>
                                          <span class="md-body-1 col-xs-4"><b>Instance</b></span>
                                          <?php echo'<md-slider ng-model="disabled4" min="1" max="50" aria-label="Disabled4" md-discrete="" id="blue-slider" class="md-primary"  style="margin-left: 60px;">';?>
                                          </md-slider>
                                          <md-input-container>
                                            <?php echo'<input type="number" id="instance" name="instance" ng-model="disabled4" min="1" max="50" ng-init="disabled4='.$instance.'" aria-label="blue" aria-controls="blue-slider">';?>
                                          </md-input-container>
                                        </md-slider-container>

                                      </md-content>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-8" style="margin-left:10px">
                                        <?php
                                            if($cache==1){
                                                echo '<div class="col-xs-6">
                                                        <label for="chkCache">With cache</label>
                                                        <input type="radio" name ="radio" class="cache" value="true" id="radio" checked/>
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                        <label for="chkCache" id="without cache">Without cache</label>
                                                        <input type="radio" name  ="radio" class="cache" value="false" id="radio">
                                                      </div>';
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                echo '<div class="col-xs-6">
                                                        <label for="chkCache">With cache</label>
                                                        <input type="radio" name ="radio" class="cache" value="false" id="radio"/>
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                        <label for="chkCache" id="without cache">Without cache</label>
                                                        <input type="radio" name  ="radio" class="cache" value="true" id="radio" checked/>
                                                      </div>';
                                            }

                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><br/>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="report">
                <center><h2><strong>Coming soon</strong></h2></center>
            </div>
        </div><hr/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>

    <!-- The below links are related to the slidebar-->
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-animate.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-route.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-aria.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.9/angular-material.js'></script>

    <script>
    angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
      .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.color = {
          red: Math.floor(Math.random() * 255),
          green: Math.floor(Math.random() * 255),
          blue: Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
        };

      });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The file image will be like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in the file which you want to pass from

```
<form action="example.php" method="post">
   <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><b>save</b></button>
   <select  name="filename" id="filename">
      <option id='file' value='".$var1.",".$var2.",".$var3."'>".$var</option>";
   </select>
</form>
```

Add the below code in the next page where you want to pass

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $myArray = explode(',', $_POST['filename']);
    for($i=0; $i<count($myArray); $i++){
        //Accessing the variables one by one as in the order of variables in value tag of the previous page
        echo $myArray[$i];
    }
}
```